# Código html no deseado al hacer actualizacion wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy haciendo actualizaciones directamente a la base de datos de wordpress, recogiendo los datos de un textarea y automáticamente al hacer la actualización se genera un `<br />`.

```php
$sentenciaPreparada = $conexion->query( $sql );
if ($sentenciaPreparada->num_rows>0) {
    while($fila= $sentenciaPreparada->fetch_assoc()){
        $menu[]=$fila;
    }
```

Cuando saco los datos no interpreta los `<br />` en el textarea.

[image: resultado]

Comment: Hola Lau, bienvenida. Y cual es tu pregunta? "Como quitar los `<br/>`?"

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a [es.so]! Además de lo que dijo lois6b... Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código como texto junto a la pregunta clara? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Comment: Montañés y jamón con acento... =)

Answer (score 1):

Ya tengo la solución que buscaba, en [ayudawp.com](https://ayudawp.com/borrar-codigo-textarea-wordpress/).

Esta función limpia el texto dentro de un textarea.

```
//Limpiar los textarea de br,p, y demás basura
function clean_textarea2($matches) {
    if ( is_array($matches) )
        $text = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . "</textarea>";
    else
        $text = $matches;

    $text = str_replace('<br />', '', $text);
    $text = str_replace('<p>', "\n", $text);
    $text = str_replace('</p>', '', $text);
    $text = str_replace('&#8220;', '"', $text);
    $text = str_replace('&#8221;', '"', $text);
    $text = str_replace('&#8216;', "'", $text);
    $text = str_replace('&#8217;', "'", $text);
    $text = str_replace('&#8242;', "'", $text);

    return $text;
}
function clean_textarea($pee, $br = 1) {
    if (strpos($pee, '<textarea') !== false)
        $pee = preg_replace_callback('!(<textarea.*?>)(.*?)</textarea>!is', 'clean_textarea2', $pee );
    return $pee;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'clean_textarea');
```

Comment: comenta el código y hace referencia a la fuente. Algún día el hipervinculo puede morir y dejarlo acá ayudaría a futuros usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Se pueden reemplazar todos los `<br />` por saltos de línea (inversa a [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php)):

```php
function br2nl($html){
    return preg_replace('@<\s*br\s*/?>@i', "\n", $html);
}
```